# Can someone help identify my vintage bike frame?

Tags: touring, identify-this-bike, vintage

I don't know a lot about bikes and bought this frame about 5 years ago in Montreal. It was repainted and looks like an old touring frame. It is very light steel, very low (close to the ground), doesn't have the original fork (1") and the bottom bracket had to be ordered from an italian manufacturer.

The photos are not great, but as I didn't know what to shoot exactly, I thought I'd give it a try.

Can someone help identify this frame?

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Probably a normal road bike, not a touring bike, given that it doesn't have rack mounts, just fender eyelets. My intuition is late 80s/early 90s, based on 7 speeds and downtube shifters.

Comment: Clearly it's a Campy (Campagnolo) frame, as that's what's stamped on the dropout.  As expected for Campy, it's a good quality frame -- forged dropouts, very nice lugs on the frame joints, well-considered cable routing.  Nice components too, though some may have been replaced.  A little hard to guess the date, but probably around 1985.

Comment: Campagnolo sold dropouts to other frame manufacturers though, didn't they? The same way Reynolds or Columbus made/make tubes, not whole bikes.

Comment: I'd go late 80s - those Shimano downtube shifters are the later boxy sort rather than rounded and thin.    Its a loverly bike - should be a good ride if it fits you.   A Campagnolo dropout with Shimano running gear suggests... something?  Not quite sure what.

Comment: I have a very similar bike from around 1989 that I bought from a LBS. It was assembled from parts and had no branding - so I am not sure a real identity can be assigned to it. Still going strong ;)

Comment: As far as I know there are no Campagnolo frames, but they did manufacture dropouts for frame builders. Since you can't downvote commenents, I'll just call bullshit on that one. The lack of shifter bosses and recessed brake mounting nuts would date this to 1980s, from lack of engravings and small serial number I'd give credit to some of the many, many small frame builder companies.

Comment: @Criggie note the Campagnolo crank with otherwise Shimano components and MTB pedals with spikes on road bike. Blasphemy!

Comment: Campy frames are super rare (and actually built by Serotta), AFAIK all neutral bikes for races (https://www.flickr.com/photos/11397373@N03/sets/72157601441665788/), and this isn't one of those. I'm with ojs on small serial means small builder. I'm guessing the cranks are original, and those may be easier to date by logo position and appearance http://velobase.com/ListComponents.aspx?SearchID=9d07c8d0-65d0-43ee-8e07-2c0348a04b89

Comment: hanks everyone. @joseph_morris nothing on here is original (@ojs as you can tell from the shimano components), neither is the crank. This is a frankenbike indeed and I just want to identify the frame. Still, seems impossible really since it was repainted. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Judging by the "fancy" joints, my guess is a conalgo frame.

Comment: I don't think it's a Colnago; there's no distinctive "club" cutout. I'm also looking at the fancy lugs, though, along with the bb cutout. The lugs remind me of my Mercian, which is not one of the really fancy ones, but just a basic 1983 Olympic model, which I think was marketed as a "sport touring" frame, with geometry middle of the road between touring and racing, but with braze-ons for 2 bottles and front and rear racks. You can image-search for Mercian, or here's a representative not-too-fancy model: http://bikeretrogrouch.blogspot.com/2013/11/vintage-mercian-retrogrouch-classic.html

Comment: However, my Mercian doesn't have cutouts in the bb, and my serial number (from 1983) is 5 digits.

Comment: The style of brake calipers should help date it. Italian BB threads narrows it a little, Campy dropouts, the derailer hanger is built in not a bolt on claw type(my '74 schwinn has the claw type). Fancy joints... I'm guessing an Italian import but some several small makers were fans of the italian stuff in that same era.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, the quick way to tell the road-race style bikes from the road-tour bikes was to look at the wheel clearance.  The race bikes would have very little clearance (~1cm) between the rear wheel and the frame, and the touring bikes tended to have closer to 5cm.

This is why from a distance it looks like a touring frame, but up close you can see that the positioning screws in the rear dropouts are missing, and the wheel settles into a location much further back than it should.  You can see the scratches in the dropout from the original wheel position.  You might want to replace those screws.

In any case, it's not a touring bike.

The Italian BB thread is a big clue.  According to https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html there were a few French makers that used Italian threads as well.